# update data from MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql

hello i create a program that can add/edit/delete data from database
i've done the Add data process but my problem is i cannot do the Edit and Delete data.
whenever i click the button Edit the Error message appear

here is the error message:

"Dynamic SQL generation for the UpdateCommand is not supported againts a SelectedCommand that does not return any key column information"

and this is my code for button edit

```
try
            {
                string contactNumVal = txtCcontact.Text;

                if (contactNumVal.Length < 11)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("The Contact Number must have 11 digit");
                }
                else
                {
                    DialogResult dw;

                    dw = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to Edit this data", "Confirm Deletion", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                    if (dw == DialogResult.Yes)
                    {


                        string MyConString = "SERVER=localhost;" +
                                                  "DATABASE=prototype_db;" +
                                                  "UID=root;";
                        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);
                        connection.Open();
                        MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("Select ClientName,ClientAddress,ClientContactNo,ClientContactPerson from client_profile where ClientName like '%"+txtCname.Text+"%'" +" ",connection);
                        da.Fill(dt);

                        dt.Rows[0].BeginEdit();
                        dt.Rows[0][0] = txtCname.Text;
                        dt.Rows[0][1] = txtCaddress.Text;
                        dt.Rows[0][2] = txtCcontact.Text;
                        dt.Rows[0][3] = txtCconPer.Text;

                        dt.Rows[0].EndEdit();
                        MySqlCommandBuilder cb = new MySqlCommandBuilder(da);
                        da.Update(dt);

                        connection.Close();


                        MessageBox.Show("Data is now updated");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(error.ToString());
            }
```

thanks for the Answers

Comment: Does your table have a primary key?

Comment: I would highly recommend looking into using `SqlCommand, SqlConnection and change that query to utilize Parameterized Query`

Comment: Try adding `Client_ID` to your `SELECT` statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DataAdapter needs to get information on the Primary Key of your table if you want it to be able to execute UPDATE and DELETE (no problems with SELECT and INSERT) but your query doesn't return this information because the Client_ID field is not enclosed in your command text

So you should change your code to

```
using(MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConString))
{
     connection.Open();
     DataTable dt = new DataTable();
     using(MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("Select Client_ID, ClientName, " + 
           "ClientAddress, ClientContactNo,ClientContactPerson " + 
           "from client_profile where ClientName like @cname",connection))
     {
         da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cname", "%" + txtCname.Text +"%");
         da.Fill(dt);
     }
 }
```

Notice also that I have removed the string concatenation of the ClientName value used in the WHERE condition. Use always parameters and not text directly typed by your user when you build sql commands. In this way you avoid SQL Injection problems and parsing problems (single quotes inside txtCName textbox would break the string concatenation)

After adding the Client_ID as above you should also change the index used to update the row values

```
dt.Rows[0][1] = txtCname.Text;
dt.Rows[0][2] = txtCaddress.Text;
dt.Rows[0][3] = txtCcontact.Text;
dt.Rows[0][4] = txtCconPer.Text;
```

Comment: Attention now, the Client_ID is the first element in the ItemArray of the DataRow[0], you should not change it.